# Flutter instalation problem, How to fix this issue?

Tags: flutter

I tried to install web dev for flutter and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJyV3.png) happened

What did I do wrong??

Comment: This is fine, it is just downloading files

Comment: This a general procedure when you switch the channel or enable something it downloads some files.

Comment: it has been looping for 12 hours, i downloaded a 4gb file under 12 hours

Answer (score 0):

It is not an issue, Flutter's web SDK update feature requires some files to be downloaded from the internet. So they are using Window's [BITS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_Intelligent_Transfer_Service) to download those required files.